# How to Set up an windows 8 phone development platform in worklight

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am newbie in worklight. I want to know, how to set up an windows 8 phone Environment in worklight. I go through IBM Environment set up for windows 8 phone. but it's not working in my case. getting this error

[image]

Please mention the **step by step setup for an windows 8 phone platform** in worklight

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Eclipse, and then in Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace search for "mobilefirst platform". Select it and install it.

This is the only installation you need to do in order to Install MobileFirst Studio.

There is no setup you need to do in Visual Studio.
You later use Visual Studio with the project you will create in MobileFirst Studio in Eclipse.

Comment: I already installed eclipse and created the environment for android. its working fine. and I also set up the environment for windows 8 phone from MobileFirst environment option in eclipse ? But when I run .csproj file in windows environment then getting the error which i mention above. so I need to know is this a set up problem or something else.

Comment: also note I am using windows 7 desktop for windows 8 phone platform.

Comment: You must run the .csproj file in a PC running the Windows 8 OS.

Comment: Is it not possible to run .csproj file in windows 7 or 8.1 desktop for windows 8 phone platform ?

Comment: Correct. You must run the .cspron in Visual Studio installed in Windows 8. This is what Microsoft requires.

Comment: Is .csproj file run in windows 8.1 ?

Comment: Yes, you can use Windows 8.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83752/discussion-between-priyank-and-idan-adar).

Comment: @Priyank, If this answer helped you, please mark as Answered.